# How get ID from save button and datetime initial and final from form?

Tags: javascript, save, postback

I'm trying make a custom event `PreSave` and I need to do some asynchronous requests, because of this I always have to return false on `PreSave` and call the postback manually.

The problem is disable the event on submit button, to workaround this I've that remove `onclick` attribute, but I can't do without the button ID.

How can I **get the ID from save button and datetime initial and final** for the current form page?

Comment: Maybe you can get an idea here: https://samsharepoint.wordpress.com/2013/05/01/change-the-default-sharepoint-ok-and-cancel-button/

Comment: Here is a related question that should be helpful. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114118/wait-async-query-in-presaveaction

Comment: Thanks, the second link was very helpful. I'd wanna know the change frequency of the ID of save button. Someone know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every eidt form has client form context object, that is called something like `WPQ2FormCtx`. This object has property `SubmitButtonID`, there ID of submit button is specified.

Keep in mind, this object name `WPQ{x}FormCtx` can be different if your master page does or does no have other web parts before the edit form web part.
Best way to determine client form context object name would be to use CSR. Add JSLink to your web part and override `OnPreRender(ctx)` event. In this event  you get render context `ctx` as parameter. This object has property `FormUniqueId` that holds form unique id value that usually is `WPQ2` or similar.

Here is sample how to use CSR and use `OnPrerender` method https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-b2eedf92

Answer (score 1):

If you use your browsers dev tools and browse the source, you can find the ID of the button with the inspector functionality.  I'd test this a bit after you implement to make sure the button ID isn't dynamic.  I don't think it is, but I would double check just in case.  In the event that it is, you can probably use jQuery to come up with a custom selector that lets you point at the button in a stable way.
[image]

Comment: I already did this, the problem is that sometimes this code changes. And I don't know why.

Comment: Try using a pseudo selector with jQuery: $("input[value='Save']")

Comment: This is a good solution to apply on save button, but time field has no attribute title and the ids are so similar, changing just some numbers inside this long code.

Comment: If you only have one field of type date/time, the parent element will have a unique class of "ms-dttimeinput".  In combination with a pseudo selector, you can narrow it down to the hours and minutes "select" elements even further.

Comment: Isn't only one, is initial and final date and time. I'm not finding a solution. Becoming depressed...

Comment: Then you can use the nth-of-type selector:  [link](https://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/)

Comment: Hmm, this can be a way. I'll try. I did think had a sharepoint function/object for manipulate the form...