# PreSaveAction: how to return true/false on asynchronous checks?

Tags: 2013, rest, form, jsom

With the **PreSaveAction** function we can perform our custom validations on the client side before committing data to the SharePoint.

In this function we must return either true or false according whether we want proceed with save or not.

But what if our validations are asynchronous? with JSOM and REST you always work  asynchronously. How can I return true or false based on my asynchronous checks?

As far as I know, we only have workarounds:

**Workaround 1**: *asynch=false* ... is deprecated

**Workaround 2**: trick the onclick handler ... replace the handler with a custom function and then execute the original handler as a callback ...

Do you know any fully JSOM/REST solution?

Answer (score 4):

In normal JavaScript programming you would want Promises... but SharePoint is not programmed to handle them, it wants a True/False from the PreSaveAction.

So the #3 workaround is to stall your code  and make it wait for the async outcomes (which can be all Promises)  with something *brutal* like `while(!asyncDone);`

I say stick to Workaround #2: [Wait async query in PreSaveAction](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114118/wait-async-query-in-presaveaction)